# String incompatibility issues c++

Tags: c++, split

I am trying to create a function that will take in a long string with " " and "," dividing different elements gained from a text file. "," represents a new line and " " represents the end of a number in the line. once split the strings should be part of an array.

```
string* splitstr(string text, string deli = " ")
{
    int start = 0;
    int end = text.find(deli);
    string *numbers[end];
    for (int i = 0; end != -1; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = text.substr(start, end - start);
        start = end + deli.size();
        end = text.find(deli, start);
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

However I am facing a problem where I get this:

```
cannot convert 'std::string**' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>**'} to 'std::string*' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*'} in return
```

How can I resolve this, or improve my function?

I was expecting to be able to store string elements in a string array and make the function return the array. I'm fairly new to programming and I started off with java so this logic might not work in c++.

Comment: Tip: Avoid `using namespace std` and use `const std::string&` as your default argument type.

Comment: Tip: Use `std::vector<std::string>` as a return type. C++ doesn't support variable length arrays by default.

Comment: The `numbers` array is a local variable that is gone after the routine returns.  The return value of `numbers` is dangling

Comment: Side note: Pretty much every time you see a pointer to a C++ container class, you're looking at a bug or overly complicated code resulting from a design mistake.

Comment: You are returning pointer to local array what leads to undefined behavior. You should use `std::vector<std::string>` as suggested above to resolve this issue.

Comment: In general it's extremely hard to return an array. Arrays always decay to a pointer when returned and the array itself goes out of scope, leaving the caller with a pointer to a deceased array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using arrays like this and instead use a `vector`

like as follows:

```
std::vector<std::string> splitstr(const std::string & text, const std::string & deli = " ")
{
    int start = 0;
    int end = text.find(deli);
    std::vector<std::string> numbers;
    for (int i = 0; end != -1; i++)
    {
        numbers.push_back(text.substr(start, end - start));
        start = end + deli.size();
        end = text.find(deli, start);
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

note this will not get the last item in the string if there is not a delimiter after it.

Comment: `deli` could be `const string&`, too.

Comment: using namespace std, should be really avoided - at least on namespace scope (it is fine in a function).

I would write https://godbolt.org/z/aEsWa6McG

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of std::vector and std::string_view.
A string_view avoids the need to allocate new output strings, the caveat is that you can only use the split result if the original input string is still in memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

auto split(std::string_view string, std::string_view delimiters)
{
    std::vector<std::string_view> substrings;
    if (delimiters.size() == 0ul)
    {
        substrings.emplace_back(string);
        return substrings;
    }

    auto start_pos = string.find_first_not_of(delimiters);
    auto end_pos = start_pos;
    auto max_length = string.length();

    while (start_pos < max_length)
    {
        end_pos = std::min(max_length, string.find_first_of(delimiters, start_pos));

        if (end_pos != start_pos)
        {
            substrings.emplace_back(&string[start_pos], end_pos - start_pos);
            start_pos = string.find_first_not_of(delimiters, end_pos);
        }
    }

    return substrings;
}

struct test_data_t
{
    std::string input;
    std::string delim;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std::string_view_literals;

    std::vector<test_data_t> test_data
    {
        { " ", " " },
        { "a", " " },
        { "aa", " " },
        { "a a", " " },
        { " a a", " " },
        { "  a a", " " },
        { "a a ", " " },
        { "`The time has come,` the Walrus said, `To talk of many things : Of shoes -- and ships -- and sealing -- wax -- Of cabbages -- and kings -- And why the sea is boiling hot --And whether pigs have wings.`", "`, -.:" }
    };

    for (const auto& [input, delim] : test_data)
    {
        auto substrings = split(input, delim);

        std::cout << substrings.size() << " : ";

        bool comma = false;
        for (const auto& substring : substrings)
        {
            if (comma) std::cout << ", ";
            std::cout << substring;
            comma = true;
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use of `std::string_view` is a good step, but your implementation is a bit to complicated: https://godbolt.org/z/9srqvhGPT

Comment: The use of find_first_of is a good idea. Your code still made string copies, so I have updated the example with pure stringview approach.

Comment: where you see a copy? Everywhere `std::string_view` is used.

Comment: Me bad, I triggered on `  r.push_back(s.substr(start, stop - start));` not realizing it was string_view's substr (but assuming std::string's substr).